# Google Apps Script - communication between script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Hi
My problem is following: I would like to create small web page, on which it will be possible to create event in Google Calendar, but with some restrictions. In my case this calendar could be  edited by my flatmates to reserve washing machine. This reservation cannot overlap and also all of us has limited number of days when we can use it.
 I have created **private calendar**, and I have created script which validate requests, and if everything is ok add event to calendar. This script is **executed as me** (because only I have permission to edit this calendar). 
But I have problem with fetching information which user execute this script (me or one of my flatmate). Class Session contains 2 methods getActiveUser() and getEffectiveUser() but active user does not work (I guess because privacy protection policy). But if I create another script which is executed as **user accessing the web** I can get active user.
Does anybody know if is it possible to communicate somehow between this 2 scripts embedeed on the same site? I want to pass email of active user from one script to another. Or maybe do you know better solution how to solve this problem?

Regards
Adam

Answer (score 3):

As you noticed, you need to set the script to run as the user accessing it to get his email. Then, instead of accessing the calendar directly (which you obviously can't) you can call another script published, but running as yourself allowing anonymous access that will receive this request from the "viewing" script and create the calendar events for it.

After you publish this "background" script, get its url and use it on a `UrlfetchApp.fetch` call to it. Then pass the parameters as url paremeters (or on payload if you prefer to use `post` instead of `get`).

The background script may even use [ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/content_service) to give nice return values to the calling script.

Comment: Any code samples for this technique? So far my attempts have flopped! I think the background app is not launching. Here is a simple version of that background app: `function doPost(e){
  if(typeof e === 'undefined')
    return;

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.add(app.createVerticalPanel());
  for(var i in e.parameter){
    panel.add(app.createLabel(i + ' : ' + e.parameter[i]));
    Logger.log(i + ' : ' + e.parameter[i]); 
  }
  return app;
}` Of course, the main problem may be that perhaps the second app will not  actually open a (new) window even if runs.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do so, but it's not as simple as you'd like.  Make your admin level script run a web service that responds to the other script.  It can probably be hacked as you can't authenticate the users, but comon, this is a washing macine!

Comment: "It can probably be hacked": I'd like to know how. Since no one has access to the code of the "public" script and it runs on Google servers. In my way of seeing it. Yes, it can be hacked if one gets access to Google Servers. But if one can do that, I feel that out personal Calendars are at risk anyway.

Comment: @Henrique - This thread is dead, but I just noticed your question.  Note that I answered before you posted your more thorough answer but I think my assertion still applies.  Security through obscurity (knowing some secret URL) generally isn't considered an effective measure.  Do note though that I wasn't saying you shouldn't do this, just be aware that your "private" calendar event creating URL could be used maliciously if it was somehow found and there'd be no audit record to tell which (user) did it because there's no authentication; the service runs as you.