# How to pass parameters from one Google-Apps-Script to another and execute?

Tags: google-apps-script

- Goal is to pass data from Google Apps Script A to Google Apps Script
  B.
- Script A is published with execute as user permissions.
- Script B    is published with execute as me permissions (owner).

At the very least I want to be able to pass `Session.getActiveUser.getEmail()` from script A to script B.

This is what I have so far...

#### Script A

```
// Script-as-app template.
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var button = app.createButton('Click Me');
  app.add(button);

  var handler = app.createServerHandler('myClickHandler');
  button.addClickHandler(handler);

  return app;
}

function myClickHandler(e) {  
  var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzSD3eh_SDnbA4a7VCkctHoMGK8d94SAPV2IURR3pK7_MwLXIb4/exec";
  var payload = { 
    name : "Gene",
    activeUser : Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
    time : new Date()
  };

  var params = { 
    method : "post",
    payload : payload
  }
  Logger.log("Hello World!");

  var HTTPResponse;

  try{
    HTTPResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  }catch(e){
    Logger.log(e);
  }
  return HTTPResponse;
}
```

#### Script B

```
function doPost(e){
  if(typeof e === 'undefined')
    return;

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.add(app.createVerticalPanel());
  for(var i in e.parameter){
    panel.add(app.createLabel(i + ' : ' + e.parameter[i]));
    Logger.log(i + ' : ' + e.parameter[i]); 
  }

  ScriptProperties.setProperty('Donkey', 'Kong');

  return app;
}
```

#### output

Going to script A [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby-bOfmG8TFHG9963ZRJCX5nOuYfbgA3UfAXqoAqKXRknue-y0/exec) the page loads the button. Clicking the button causes "Hello World!" to be logged in Script A's project log but the log of Script B's project remains empty.
TryCatch does not log any error.

Comment: Have you logged thé e.parameter.netId value ? What ils tour issue exactly ?

Comment: With what I had before I couldn't get any logged values.
I put a form in script 1 and used that pass text to script 2 and it worked (passed text and used it to add sheet).
What I have now does something pretty weird. The UrlFetchApp's httpResponse is a google login page that doesn't work and just redirects you to an actual login (even when already logged in) which when you login redirects you to the script 2's doGet function which throws an error.

Comment: Update: I added "followRedirects":false to the params and get a 
"Moved Temporarily

The document has moved [here](https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&continue=https%3a%2f%2fscript.google.com%2fmacros%2fs%2fAKfycby9wbmuPV2nfFj2%5f%5fCwka%5fM8Dn1LR3-SVkJtPon6PjtNZNOA-FX%2fexec&followup=https%3a%2f%2fscript.google.com%2fmacros%2fs%2fAKfycby9wbmuPV2nfFj2%5f%5fCwka%5fM8Dn1LR3-SVkJtPon6PjtNZNOA-FX%2fexec)."

Comment: are you sure about your deployed version and not using the .dev url for script 2?

Comment: Interesting technique. I am facing essentially the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506058/apps-script-webapp-how-to-authenticate-bigquery). You say: _Going to script A here the page loads the button. Clicking the button causes "Hello World!" to be logged in Script A's project log but the log of Script B's project remains empty._ I clicked your link and your code seemed to work, since the script B button had my email address. It is odd that the script B logger does not work, but it does look like the params are being passed -- that is already great! (Thanks!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your problem is due that you try to pass as a response argument a uiapp element.
here a little variation of your script in html service.
the [demo](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxXGvzMKpHmlz2D8yD_YKxmpj2AsoB0FgraWOoKmaA31NQnDPvH/exec)
 the script:

```
// #### Part A
function doGet(e) {
  var html ="<input type='text' id='text' /><input type='button' onclick='myClick()' value='submit'>"; // a text to be passed to script B
  html+="<div id='output'></div>"; // a place to display script B answer
  html+="<script>";
  html+="function myClick(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showResults).myClickHandler(document.getElementById('text').value);}"; // handler to do the job in script A
  html+="function showResults(result){document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result;}</script>"; // function to show the result of the urlfetch (response of script B)
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
}


function myClickHandler(text) {  
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  var payload = { 
    name : "Gene",
    text : text,
    time : new Date()
  };

  var params = { 
    method : "post",
    payload : payload
  }
  Logger.log("text: "+text);

  var HTTPResponse;

  try{
    HTTPResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  }catch(e){
    Logger.log(e);
  }
  return HTTPResponse.getContentText();
}

// ###### Part B
function doPost(e){
  if(typeof e === 'undefined'){
    return "e was empty!!"; 
  }
  var htmlOut="<ul>"; 
  for(var i in e.parameter){
    htmlOut+="<li>"+i+ " : " + e.parameter[i]+"</li>";
    if(i=="text"){
      htmlOut+="<li> Text hash : "+Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, e.parameter[i]))+"</li>";
    }
  }
  htmlOut+="</ul>";
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(htmlOut);
}
```

It is important to note that you won't have the ability to get the logger events of the script B (because it is triggered when you are not there - you are not the one who trigger script B. this is script A that's trigger script B and script A is not identified as "you" when it make a urlfetch). If you want to get the result of the script b logger you should return it to the script a.
It's important to note: again, when script A do the UrlFetch to script B it is not identified as "you" so the script B must accept to be opened by anyone (in the publish option under "Who has access to the app:" you need to select anyone even anonymous).

NB: i put everything in the same script for commodity (you can split that in two differents script it's not a problem) and because B part need to be accessed to anonymous persons I can't retrieve automatically the email adress in the part A so I changed a little bit what was done here.

Comment: I've tried a lot of different approaches with varying success and definitely like yours.

Comment: I would like to adapt this to the scenario where you want two apps to run. AFAIK, this solution does not allow me to bring along parameters when I call a new web app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370072/google-apps-script-communication-between-script is essentially what I'm trying to do, but that question does not offer the code that will do it. Any suggestions for that variation on your code?

Comment: Clarification: unlike the example I cited, I want to actually open the second app for interaction, and have two different authorizations: for script A: the user; for B: me.

Comment: @wgw If I understood, you want that the 2 scripts, while alive, exchange data. When script 1 receive fresh data from 2, it will automatically update his display. The above scripts aren't a use here, they only exchange data when first called. I don't believe a clean solution exist. But, here what I can propose you: on client side (html service) create a function that will fetch server data on a regular time basis. On the server side the function check a shared spreadsheet with the other script and serve back the data. It's not clean nor quick but I don't have other idea. Good Luck in your quest

Comment: Thanks! The simpler scenario is where I open a second webapp *window* with parameters passed from the first webapp. An html link in the first app (script A) will do that. But I want to pass more than just a parameter; I want to pass the client's email address and the fact that the client is logged into Google at the time of the call to the second app (the first app identifies the user and runs as Anyone; the second runs as me.) I can pass the email address, but I would not know that the client is still logged in. If I find a neat solution, I will post a link here. Thanks again!

Comment: Well I'm almost sure that when he will click the link generated by the first script he is still connected. Unless he is really vicious and load the app to have the link displayed, disconnect and then only click the link. Here an idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399428/add-an-open-url-handler-to-a-button/21402228#21402228 so when he click the link it will also fire a server function (in this case it just write data to a spreadsheet, but you can imagine it's doing an authentification action - urlfetch -...)