# Apps Script webapp: how to authenticate bigquery?

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I am trying to get my apps script webapp to execute as "user accessing the webapp", but its bigquery should run as me, the developer. (If I run the webapp as me, everything works...) I looked at the documentation at https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization. There is no apps script example, so I tried to get the javascript example working.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

  function auth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {
        gapi.client.load('bigquery', 'v2');
        $('#client_initiated').html('BigQuery client authorized');
        $('#auth_button').fadeOut();
        $('#dataset_button').fadeIn();
    });
  }

  // User Submitted Variables
  var projectNumber = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
  var clientId = 'XXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';

  var config = {
    'client_id': clientId,
    'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'
  };

  function listDatasets() {
    var request = gapi.client.bigquery.datasets.list({
      'projectId':projectNumber
    });
    request.execute(function(response) {
        $('#result_box').html(JSON.stringify(response.result.datasets, null));
    });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="auth_button" onclick="auth();">Authorize</button>
<div id="client_initiated"></div>
<button id="dataset_button" style="display:none;" onclick="listDatasets();">Show datasets</button>
<div id="result_box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I generated a client id as a browser app with https://script.google.com as the server address. With the code above, I get this error: Cannot read property 'authorize_m___' of undefined.

My question is twofold: 1) Would an apps script webapp authenticate in the same way as the javascript app authenticates? I.e. can I use that code  as a guide for my apps script?

And 2) any suggestions about how to debug the javascript sample code? Note that I ran this code as an apps script webapp.... That is probably an error....

Comment: Continuing the saga: it looks like the authorization has to go through a server, even when using apps scripts: `If your application is a publicly accessible online dashboard, you'll need to securely proxy the requests through a server-side application, such as a Google App Engine application. BigQuery queries must be charged to a specific project, so the Google App Engine app should keep track of the requests being made to ensure they represent legitimate usage of your application.`  That seems odd, because a transaction function can be totally hidden and so secrets could be passed secretly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer... or workaround answer is given here: [How to pass parameters from one Google-Apps-Script to another and execute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498552/how-to-pass-parameters-from-one-google-apps-script-to-another-and-execute)

I can use two stage authentication in place of direct authentication: the user logs in as him/herself, I get the user's name to find their files, then switch to a webapp that uses BigQuery and execs as me, the developer.

A good workaround for advanced services authentication under apps scripts....