# UrlFetchApp fetch a google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, fetch

From a Google apps script I'm trying to use UrlFetchApp to fetch another Google apps script. I tried to make it as basic as possible but it's still giving me an error.
The first script called 'frontend' executes as the user and the second script 'backend' executes as the owner of 'backend'.

#### frontend

```
var backend = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwdwQdYYMwqofjEqFn3ozz_LqQ87qj7ZX19sYmelX9dUtP8aNxf/exec';

function doGet(e) {
 return UrlFetchApp.fetch(backend) 
}
```

#### backend

```
function doGet(e) {
  return doPost(e);
}

function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.createLabel('Backend'));
  return app;
}
```

frontend is published [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby1te7gUMEAVNBOmAHiemU4UsSVJ77JfRLCYtjOmtU6yJHc304/exec)

#### extra information

```
Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.getRequest(backend)) =>
{useIntranet=false, 
followRedirects=true, 
payload=, 
method=get,
validateHttpsCertificates=true, 
contentType=application/x-www-form-urlencoded,
url=https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwdwQdYYMwqofjEqFn3ozz_LqQ87qj7ZX19sYmelX9dUtP8aNxf/exec}
```

- Using instead an html form I can correctly sent POST/GET parameters from one google script to another using hidden input elements to define parameters.
- If I try to do what the html form is doing using javascript - jquery ajax the request returns an error.

I'm very confused as to why a simple html form within a google script can request another google script but a javascript request from a google script to another google script is denied by what appears to be security policy issues.

Answer (score 0):

You dont say how youve published them exactly but i bet your backend isnt published to allow anonymous users. Do so.

Comment: Both were published as 'anyone'. I changed backend to 'anyone, including anonymous' but it still causes "google drive encountered an error page..."

Comment: the "anonymous" is really important! as the scripts do the urlfetch anonymously. You can check a working sample here (try using html service instead os uiapp): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498552/how-to-pass-parameters-from-one-google-apps-script-to-another-and-execute/21534705#21534705