# Calling a google app script from a web page

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a script for managing a google spreadsheet.

I have 2 buttons on this spreadsheet which call 2 different functions

I'd like to call these functions from 2 buttons in a web site (maybe a google site) and I'd like to do this in the simplest way.

Can I for example give a link to each function and when these links are clicked the functions run?

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is so many way to do that, html service, uiapp, parameter passed to a doGet function (that's the link trick)...
you should read the tutorials given by the google apps script team.
- for html service https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#user_objects
- for uiapp: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service#ServerHandlers
- for url parameters: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content

Comment: I'm trying to using url parameters.
I get the google url and i put a doGet method into my code but i dont know how to call this method with this url.

Comment: If i Try to call that link the result is:

TypeError: Impossibile chiamare il metodo "getSheetByName" di null.

Comment: How can I use the doGet() with paramiters so i can choose which metod i wanna call?

Like:

    doGet(int i){
        if i = 0 call method1()
        else call method2()
     }

Sorry for the pseudocode :P

Comment: if you have doGet(e) you can access e vals with: e.parameter.val or you can also do something like Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e.parameter)) to see all the parameters. here an exemple with a doPost (same as the doGet): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498552/how-to-pass-parameters-from-one-google-apps-script-to-another-and-execute/21534705#21534705 you should also look at that ticket talking about getting event parameters from a google form: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3610